# Reading Last Line of a text file C#

Tags: c#, file-handling

I am using following piece of code to read last line of text file: What is wrong with this code. I have written the complete error generated by debugger below. What will be the mistake I am doing ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
//using System.Linq;
namespace fileHandling
{
    class Program
    {
        public void GetDataFromFile()
        {


            // opening stream !!!
            FileStream fo = new FileStream("hello.txt", FileMode.Open);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fo);

            if (!File.Exists("hello.txt"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} does not exist.", "hello.txt");

            }

            else
            {
                //string record;
                //record = sr.ReadLine();
                string lastLine = File.ReadLines("hello.txt").Last();
                Console.WriteLine(lastLine);
            }
            sr.Close();
           fo.Close();

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.GetDataFromFile();
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
System.IO.IOException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024864
  Message=The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\nabeel\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\fileHandling\fileHandling\bin\Debug\hello.txt' because it is being used by another process.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
       at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
       at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
       at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
       at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding)
       at System.IO.File.ReadLines(String path)
       at fileHandling.Program.GetDataFromFile() in c:\Users\nabeel\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\fileHandling\fileHandling\Program.cs:line 32
       at fileHandling.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\nabeel\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\fileHandling\fileHandling\Program.cs:line 60
  InnerException:
```

Comment: My first guess would be the file is open in some other program (text editor etc.)

Comment: and try removing the filestream and stream reader, this could also cause the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have opened the FileStream which has locked the file, but then don't use it to read the file instead you are using File.ReadLines just remove the below lines and it all work fine.

```
FileStream fo = new FileStream("hello.txt", FileMode.Open);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fo);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure that the problem was so small , but cause trouble for beginners like me !

Answer (score 1):

You open the file here:

```
FileStream fo = new FileStream("hello.txt", FileMode.Open);
```

Then you fail to close it.

You don't even need that line or the one below it. Just remove them.

(If you leave those lines in, use `fo.Close()` or `fo.Dispose()` to close the file.)

Answer (score 1):

Don't open it via `FileStream` and use the `File.ReadLines`.

Remove these lines and see if that works better for you

```
FileStream fo = new FileStream("hello.txt", FileMode.Open);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fo);
```